# Is it possible to override only required abstract methods in interface or Abstract classes among n-methods?

Tags: java

Is it possible to override only some abstract methods in interface among set of abstract methods?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can provided you make that class also as `abstract`.

Answer (score 2):

> ***Is it possible to override only some abstract methods in interface***

Yes, but since the resulting class is **still not fully [concrete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28computer_programming%29#Concrete)**, this class has to be declared `abstract`.

This compiles fine:

```
interface MyInterface {
    void method1();
    void method2();
}

abstract class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    public void method1() { }
}
```

(but it won't compile without the `abstract` modifier).

Answer (score 0):

If you can implement some abstract methods by making the class itself abstract, as its not fully implemented. 
Ex:

```
public interface ITest {

    public void add();

    public void sub();
}
```

is your interface and class is like :

```
abstract class  IClass implements ITest
{

    @Override
    public void add() {     

    }
}
```

is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a concrete class that extends an abstract class but need not to implement its abstract methods.